# Triple LED has only 4 terminals

Tags: led

All of the LED cathodes have been connected together. I want to regulate them with an MCU but I think the fact that the cathodes are connected on the diodes makes it impossible for me to wire it up so I can get my opamp follower working.

[image]

Here is my almost completed circuit (notice the opamp inverting inputs arent connected and also i need circuits for the mcu outputs too) where i have three outputs from the microcontroller (naturally it must be grounded somewhere so one end of those outputs are connected together) and then the LED cathodes are also connected together. Is there any way for me to get this wired up without needing to have 3 separate microcontrollers if i'm using this particular led configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already bought the LEDs? Otherwise try to find them in common anode, or just separated (6 connections). If you have common anode you can connect this to your V+ and use three times the schematic of the current source you were working on.
The separated are the most flexible, because you can also put them in series in three color branches, which you can't with common anode/cathode.

Comment: yeah, the ones I got from digikey are all separated so they're fine, but these I got from dealextreme seem to have common cathode (the connections are: R+, G+, B+, -)

Comment: Actually it appears these are mislabeled, or I am interpreting it backwards. either way it's the positive end of the diodes that are connected together. I think I might be able to make the circuit work this way! and on 5V too

Comment: @Steven - great! But is this a different project from what you did before? Don't you want to place a number of them in series this time?

Comment: I guess putting these common anode units in series would be difficult `:(`   These led's appear to be Luxeon III's. The ones I was working with were Cree XP-E's on separate dies and have all terminals. I also have a Cree XR-E RGBW which also has all terminals. The thing is that the Crees are a good deal more expensive but it may turn out to be worth it.

Comment: I may use a transistor for each one and have a linear array of them or a 3x3 square (I have 10.. hmm the arduino does not have that many outputs.. well it would be 30 of them). They were about $3 each, compared to the $11 the XP-E assemblies are.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the inverting opamp inputs to the tops of their respective LED resistors.  That will make the LED plus resistor voltage follow what your voltage sources are doing.  The opamp and transistor only give it more current drive capability.

That will work fine, but be quite inefficient.  The LED will use only a small part of the 12V.  The LED current times the remaining voltage will be burned up as heat.  You didn't say what kind of LEDs these are or how much current you want to run thru them, so maybe this doesn't matter.

Since you've got a lot of voltage to start with, you might as well make the LED resistors bigger.  That will give better current regulation from the drive voltage.  You're still going to create the same heat, this will just shift some from the transistors to the resistors.

For the optimum current regulation, size the resistors so you get the maximum LED current with maybe 9-10V at the top of the resistor.  This leaves a little headroom for the opamp and transistor to work with, but will make the LED current largely independent of small variations of the LED voltage.

You didn't say what voltage the signal sources are.  Assuming they are 0-5V, you can put a resistor divider in the feedback path instead of making is a direct connection.  For example, two 1 KOhm resistors will divide the feedback signal by 2, effectively giving the opamp a gain of 2.  The 0-5V signal will now be a 0-10V signal at the top of the LED resistor.  Size the resistor accordingly and that will work well.  It will also shift the worst case heat dissipation from the transistor to the resistor.

For example, let's say these are 100mA white LEDs, which drop 3.2V at that current.  10V - 3.2V = 6.8V accross the resistor at full on.  6.8V / 100mA = 68 Ohms.  At full on, the resistor will dissipate 100mA * 6.8V = 680mW, so a 1W or 2W resistor will work.  The transistor will have its maximum dissipation when dropping half the voltage between the power supply and the LED.  The total voltage drop of the transistor plus resistor is 12V - 3.2V = 8.8V.  If half that is accross the transistor, then the same is accross the resistor, which lets us determine the current.  4.4V / 68Ohms = 65mA, and the power in each of the transistor and resistor at that point is 4.4V * 65mA = 285mW.  That's a bit too much for a SOT23, but a SOT89 with a little extra copper around it should be able to handle that.  Anything bigger, like a TO220 standing up for the board can handle it too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to replace your NPN driver transistors with PNP transistors.  That solves your overhead problem.  Or you could keep the NPNs and move the current limiting resistors to the high side of the driver NPNs.

You will probably need base resistors if you use PNPs; and should still increase the current limiting resistors which are inline with the LEDs.  If you have a problem keeping the op-amp outputs high enough to keep the PNPs off, then a diode in the high-side leg of the PNP would help.